# Convert html code into actionscript code

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript

How can i convert this HTML code into Action script code, i am an android and actionscript developer, i dont know much about HTML and java script. i have tried different forums, i know it can be converted, can someone help me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
adroll_adv_id = "JD5ZGBNO4RBYVAMMMPX3J7";
adroll_pix_id = "CEJOJM5N5VAHBKCVMT2DML";
(function () {
var oldonload = window.onload;
window.onload = function(){
__adroll_loaded=true;
var scr = document.createElement("script");
var host = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://s.adroll.com" : "http://a.adroll.com");
scr.setAttribute('async', 'true');
scr.type = "text/javascript";
scr.src = host + "/j/roundtrip.js";
((document.getElementsByTagName('head') || [null])[0] ||
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode).appendChild(scr);
if(oldonload){oldonload()}};
}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the code you listed is actually javascript encased in a html tag.  Javascript and actionscript are pretty similar, you should be able to  use the same code with minimal changes.  Just use the javascript as a reference to code it with actionscript

Comment: can you please explain to me that what exactly is this code doing?

Comment: Looks to me like its loading advertisement